# How to set a modules settings in Drupal 7 programmatically? (admin settings) ( not with hook_form_alter() )

Tags: drupal-7, settings, admin

I have modules coming with empty admin setup page.

I'd like to set up this module programmatically.

This page is basically a form. I know I can change this form with hook_form_alter() however for this to work I need to go to this page and press save. This is NOT what i'd like to achieve, I'd like to do it programmatically.

What are my options?

(These modules are not my custom codes. I have them from drupal.org so I have them as they are, I need to write my code that makes this happen. (a module ideally))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Closest answer can be found here: [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/45587/38552)
Which says:

> look at [drupal_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) to programmatically submit a form -- its like visiting the form in a webpage and submitting it without ever opening a browser window. Whatever logic that form does upon submission -- will still happen

Another solution can be that it is storing data as a variable, or just in the database somewhere.

Comment: There's [Configuration Management] (https://www.drupal.org/project/configuration) module as well which promises the option of version controlling it's data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the module's code. Most likely, it is storing its configuration in variables, so you should just be able to set the variable from your own code and dodge the form altogether.